# Apex rest outbound access token

Tags: apex

Below code is working fine for rest outbound. I am getting the access token using postman tool and passing the same in below program. But I want generate access token using user name, password, client Id, client secret in below program. kindly update below code to generate access token and pass in req.setHeader. Thanks

```
        Httprequest req=new httprequest();
         Http http = new Http();
        String endPointURL='https://domainName/services/apexrest/Account10/';
        req.setendpoint(endPointURL);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml; charset=utf-8');
        req.setBody('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><request><name>'+accName+'</name></request>');
        req.setmethod('POST');

        req.setHeader('Authorization','Authorization: Bearer '+Access_Token);

        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        response=res.getbody();
        return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one sample curl request which you can use to get Session Id

```
curl https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token -d "grant_type=password" -d "client_id=myclientid" -d "client_secret=myclientsecret"
-d "username=mylogin@salesforce.com" -d "password=mypassword123456"
```

You must provide your client id, client secret, username, and password with user security token appended.

[Step Two: Set Up Authorization](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm)

Comment: Hi @Tushar Sharma. i got session id/ access token in post man using url: https://domainName/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&client_id=3MV--&client_secret=706---&username=username@test.com&password=123123+securitytoken. but i want to pass inside above apex program. I think you got my point.

Comment: https://domainName/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&client_id=3MV--&client_secret=706---&username=username@test.com&password=123123+securitytoken. but i want to pass client id, client secret, username, and password with user security token inside above apex program and generate access token/session id dynamically. Because if i hard code access token, then every tme i wil have to update it with new one.

Comment: @SFDC yes for that you need too convert this curl request to APEX request. As you have made another request so I think you can easily do this as well using sample provided.